# Why the mouse up event is triggered twice?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-water-vtm2st?file=/src/index.js) is my code.

The code is that when the user mouse down on a table cell, I want to
update the cell index and the row index of the state variable.
When the mouse button is up, I want to use the cell index and the row index of the state variable to update the border colour of the cell.

When the mouse button is up, the `endSelect` function will be called. The `endSelect` function just prints the state variable.

The problem is why the `endSelect` function is called twice when I click on the table cell.
I have removed the <StrictMode> tag from the index.js, but the problem still exists.

Comment: I see you are using vanilla JavaScript features: addEventListener, removeEventListener. This might create inconsistencies when using this in react. Also it is still not clear what you are trying to achieve,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **useEffect** should be like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    const mouseup = () => uiAction.endSelect();
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
    };
}, [uiAction]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem still exists.

Comment: @TheKNVB can you check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-swirles-75l3pf?file=/src/component/TestingTable.js:211-427)

Comment: I overlook something.
thank you very much